# pgfkeys and ifs

Tags: tikz-pgf, conditionals, tikz-styles, pgfkeys, ifthenelse

I'm still looking for a viable solution to have "conditional pictures", or pictures, where I can enable and disable certain parts of the pictures with styles (very much like beamer overlays).

My aim is to have `pic` where I can add a style `dontdrawitnow` that will suppress a certain part of the picture.

My implementation so far:

```
\documentclass[tikz,png]{standalone}
\begin{document}
    \newif\ifdrawit
    \tikzset{
        drawit/.initial=true,
        dontdrawitnow/.style={drawit=false},
        drawit/.is if=drawit,
        mypic/.pic={
            \node at (-3,0) {\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/drawit}};
            \ifdrawit
                \node {I'm drawing it!};
            \else
                \node[drawit=true] {Maybe next time!};
            \fi
        }
    }
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \pic                at (0,0) {mypic};
        \pic[dontdrawitnow] at (0,1) {mypic};
        \pic                at (0,2) {mypic};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

It initially sets a key `drawit` to true. Whenever I apply a certain style `dontdrawit`, the value is set to false. I bind the key to an `\if`. Whenever I draw the `pic`, it looks at the value of the key to decide whether to draw something or not, afterwards it resets the key to `true`.

At least that's what I thought it does. Instead, the output is:

[image]

What's going on? Neither is the `\ifdrawit` being executed correctly, nor is the key ever being set to false!

And it gets funnier. Just for fun, remove this line:

```
        drawit/.is if=drawit,
```

Then the output is:

[image]

The key is now set correctly! (And of course the `\ifdrawit` doesn't react, since it's not set now.)

What's going on here? Am I completely misunderstanding how `.is if` works? Or is it just broken?

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't quite understand what you are trying to do here… Also, to set a conditional to true, use `\drawittrue` and set it to false with `\drawitfalse`. As I see it now, it is false all the way through your document. `drawit=false` just confuses me here,

Comment: @RunarTrollet, I'm trying to use pgfkeys for setting the key. It is supposed to execute `\drawittrue` and `drawitfalse` (see pgfmanual 3.0.1a, page 889) when I put `drawit=true` or `drawit=false`.

Comment: @RunarTrollet, ahh, but you're pointing in the correct direction! When I execute `drawit/.is if=drawit`, it doesn't initialise the TeX-if with the current value of the key!

Answer (score 2):

RunarTrollet has pointed me in the right direction. `/.is if` does really exactly what it states in the manual, and *only* that. There are two reasonable things you might expect that it *doesn't* do:

- When executing `drawit/.is if=drawit`, it *doesn't* store the current value of the key in the TeX-if. (So you have to initialise the value afterwards!)
- When executing `drawit=somevalue` afterwards, it *doesn't* store the value `somevalue` in the key.

So the correctly behaving code seems to be this:

```
\documentclass[tikz,png]{standalone}
\begin{document}
    \newif\ifdrawit
    \tikzset{
        drawit/.is if=drawit,
        drawit=true,
        dontdrawitnow/.style={drawit=false},
        mypic/.pic={
            \ifdrawit
                \node {I'm drawing it!};
            \else
                \node {Maybe next time!};
            \fi
        }
    }
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \pic                at (0,0) {mypic};
        \pic[dontdrawitnow] at (0,1) {mypic};
        \pic                at (0,2) {mypic};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

And the result is:

[image]

As cfr points out in the comments, you don't need the `[drawit=true]`-option in the node, as assignments to `\ifdrawit` are local to a TeX-group.

Comment: What is the point of the `drawit=true` in the `\node` option? `\node {Maybe next time!};` does the same thing, doesn't it?

Comment: @cfr, then I don't understand it. I thought I was resetting the `\ifdrawit` to true! Why do you think I can leave it out?

Comment: Did you try it? You don't need to reset it ... I think it is only getting changed to false within a TeX group. So, once you leave that group, you are back with the initial value regardless.

Comment: @cfr I tried it, and it behaves like you said. Your explanation seems reasonable, so I'll edit.